# Show that Skolemization preserves satisfiability

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Consider replacing an existential quantifier with a $n$-ary Skolem function symbol $f$ and suppose that there is an $\mathcal{M}$ model that:
$\mathcal{M} \models \forall x_1\dots \forall x_n \exists y P(x_1, \dots, x_n, y)$. How can I show there is an $\mathcal{M}'$ interpretation such that:

$\mathcal{M}' \models \forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n P(x_1, \dots, x_n, f(x_1, \dots, x_n))$.

Comment: Define a function $f^D: D^n \to D$, where $D$ is the domain of the model $\mathcal M$, such that for every $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in D : f^D(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=a$, where $a \in D$ is such that $\mathcal M \vDash P(a_1,\ldots,a_n,a)$. Thus, the function $f^D$ is the required interpretation for the function symbol $f$.